# jquery data function to object tag

Tags: jquery, flash, object

I am using swfupload with jqueryui datepicker:

1. Open the datepicker
2. Close or leave the datepicker
3. click the upload button (which is swf and in html shown as `<object>` tag.

The problem only occurs in IE9 which is an jquery ui exception
-> Missing instance data for this datepicker.

When I debugged it, the problem occurs at this point.
-> `return $.data(a,PROP_NAME)`
a is object element, and PROP_NAME is just a string 'datepicker'

When I just type that to IE7, 8 and chrome, they return undefined cause there is no data named 'datepicker' bound to that object.. but IE9 throws exception.

I did some googling and couldn't find any discussions about this.

I was thinking of covering the object element with span and when a click event occurs in that span, dynamically trigger an click event to the swf object.. but to do that I think I'm going to need some external stuff... so I am leaving it out..

Anyone has any idea how to figure it out, or some advice?

Comment: can you post up some actual code please?

Answer (score 2):

I also experienced the exact same issue: it occurred while using jquery-ui datepicker and [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) (which uses flash and therefore an object tag). IE 9 only.

As you already identified, the issue is with jquery-ui. The only way I found to fix this was to modifiy the minified jquery-ui code by removing the following exception code:

throw"Missing instance data for this datepicker"

This prevents jquery-ui from throwing the exception which means uploadify can continue and won't be affected.

Obviously the draw backs are:

1. It's a modification to a framework script so it could get inadvertently overwritten (the exception code might be resotred) if a new or updated version of jquery-ui is added to your application in the future; and
2. The exception is no longer being handled i.e. the code won't throw the error "Missing instance data for this datepicker" any more, even if it is valid and should be 'known about'. Therefore, it could cause problems debugging datepicker if it's not working for some other reason.

Comment: Same problem here... Its funny that uploadify throw datepicker exception :-D found this: http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8993